# Error in Kohana 3.1.3.1 with rowanparker paypal module

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

**rowanparker**

https://github.com/rowanparker/kohana-3-paypal

I really need this module but I can not use it because it gives me this error:

```
Call to undefined method PayPal_ExpressCheckout::SetExpressCheckout()
```

NOTE: I did everything as in the example on GitHub.

**shadowhand**

https://github.com/shadowhand/paypal

I get the same error with this module.

Can someone help me on this? PLEASE!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `set()` method instead of `SetExpressCheckout()`

Comment: That problem doesn't concern this question at all, I really can't help :)